# All my threads get stuck on HTTPClient.GetAsync() but no requests are ever sent from my application

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpclient

I'm making a large number of API requests and I've noticed that sometimes the application seems to get "stuck" on HTTPClient.GetAsync(). I have a queue of requests, and each time a request is made, it makes a task for it so it can quickly move onto the next one and not wait for it to return.

Almost randomly the threads will start piling up till I reach my thread pool limit. They all pile up on `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request)).Result;`. If I set a timeout on the HTTPClient, it never times out. By using microsoft Network monitor, I've been able to determine that none of the requests are actually sent when this starts happening.

This is not reliably reproducible. I can go 100 requests, or 10,000 requests before this starts happening.

The offending code:

```
private T Get<T>(string endpoint, IRequest request) where T : class
    {
        return Get2<T>(endpoint, request).Result;
    }

    private async Task<T> Get2<T>(string endpoint, IRequest request) where T : class
    {
        var client = InitHttpClient();

        string debug = BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request)).Result;
        string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body, _serializerSettings);

            return result;
        }

        var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HelpScoutError>(body);
        throw new HelpScoutApiException(error, body);
    }
```

Note: After reading this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html I switched my code to what you see above as a test. The threads now get stuck on: `return Get2<T>(endpoint, request).Result;`

Edit: The code before changing it:

```
        private async <T> Get<T>(string endpoint, IRequest request) where T : class
    {
        var client = InitHttpClient();

        string debug = BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request)).Result;
        string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body, _serializerSettings);

            return result;
        }

        var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HelpScoutError>(body);
        throw new HelpScoutApiException(error, body);
    }
```

What can I do to debug this? Any insight on what could be causing this?

Edit2: After some more searching, could this be caused by a deadlock of some sort? I am making a new HTTPClient for each request (Which I understand is a bit bad) so I thought that would not happen.

Edit3: This is the API client what I am working in, any of the `Get` methods lead to the code I have posted about. https://github.com/Selz/HelpScoutNet/blob/master/src/HelpScoutClient.cs

Comment: How (and why) do you "make a task" from the queue? Why don't you simply call `Get2` and, if necessary `ContinueWith(...)` whatever you want to do when it comes back? You shouldn't need a separate thread pool thread waiting for a Result when there's already a Task<T> you can wait on. That will just starve the pool and when a result does finally come back there will be no thread to service it.

Comment: I have made a request queue that utilizes an API client that contains the code you see here, it will make a Task for a method in the client that eventually ends up at GetAsync(). The Task this method returns is only a test, I am less concerned about starving the threadpool than I am about finding out why they all seem to stall at this point. I can worry about fixing any poor performance or poor structure afterwards, I've been hacking together different proposed solutions for nearly a week now without figuring this out so there is a lot of messy code laying around.

Comment: Here are two ideas to try: (1) change the body assignment to `string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` and (2) change the Get<T> method to `return Task.Run(() => Get2<T>(endpoint, request)).Result;`

Comment: Thanks Paul, could you describe what those two changes actually do? It's going to take an hour or two to see if this happens again so I have plenty of time to learn.

Comment: Additionally, can I just make a synchronous Get request? I really don't need a task here, since I already make a task in my queue it would be fine to block while waiting for the response.

Comment: The problem is that you "followed" the advice in Cleary's article only by pushing the blocking call up one method in the call stack. You didn't avoid blocking on async code; you just did it somewhere else. But you're still blocking the same thread, so if the problem is in fact due to that thread being blocked (i.e. some kind of deadlock), moving the blocking expression hasn't solved anything. All that said, without more details it will be difficult if not impossible to actually say for sure what's wrong. What I can say is, **get rid of `.Result` _completely_ and use `await` instead**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Please excuse my ignorance. But my understanding thus far is that if you want to return a value from an async method, you have to return a task. And to get the value of that you either need a method that returns void and you await the task, or you must also return a task. How would you return the value from a method without using .Result on a task?

The API need to continue to return the objects it always has, unless the fix is to have the API return tasks and the user would just await that.

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question without a specific _complete_ code example. Most often, as soon as you start using `async` methods, you have to use them all the way up to the top of the call stack (e.g. to the event handler that initiated the operation). If you find yourself in a situation where it's literally impossible to `await` your async method, then another option is to register a continuation explicitly using the `Task.ContinueWith()` method.

Comment: The key is to remember that the whole point of using asynchronous operations of any kind is so that your current thread need not wait; in some cases, this is critical, because that thread is needed for other critical operations and blocking it is very bad. Whatever you do, you need to adjust your caller so that it can cope with the called `async` method returning **before the operation has completed**, and do so without blocking the current thread.

Comment: Thank you Peter, "you have to use them all the way up to the top of the call stack" was very helpful. That's what I suspected. In this case I just need to make a Get request that is not intended to be async and will block the thread since it will be literally impossible to use async methods all the way up the call stack while keeping this API functioning the same.

Comment: What type of application is this? (Console? WPF? Web API?)

Comment: This is a WPF application, however I can use this API client with a console application or anything else and the same issue occurs. I've opted to make an async version of the client to fit my needs instead, since I have no clue how to make HTTPClient.GetAsync() not deadlock under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that this was most likely a deadlocking issue.

I was trying to use the HttpClient in an async manner on multiple threads, this would periodically result in what I can only ascertain was a deadlock scenario.

I corrected this by building out an async client for this library, ensuring that anyc methods are used up the entire call stack. After utilizing a fully async compatible library, the problem vanished.